# Base fragment for same fragments with different arguments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the in-built boilerplate for BottomNavigationView to build an app with three fragments which get data from an api.

All three fragments call the data from the same api with different arguments. But this same code is used in all the fragments, only the `categoryid` changes in each api call. Is extending an abstract base fragment an efficient way to reduce code duplication? How do I pass the argument `categoryid` from the child fragment to base fragment?

I don't want to create one fragment and one layout for all three menu items so as to save state of each fragment and avoid making api calls on each navigation change.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
public class ABCFragment extends Fragment {

    private RestAPI restAPI;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    static Context context;
    private boolean mTwoPane = false;
    int layoutId = 0;
    int categoryid = 1; //default value
    int langId = 1;

    private FragmentABCBinding abcBind;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        abcBind = FragmentABCBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        if (abcBind.detail != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }

        recyclerView = abcBind.list;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

    
        createRestAPI();
        restAPI.getAPI(langId, categoryid).enqueue(abcCallback); //CATEGORYID is the argument which differentiates each fragment
        return abcBind.getRoot();
    }



    private void createRestAPI() {
        HttpService okhttpClient = new HttpService(context);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okhttpClient.getHttpClient())
                .baseUrl(RestAPI.ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        restAPI = retrofit.create(restAPI.class);
    }


    Callback<ListWrapper<ResponseList>> abcCallback = new Callback<ListWrapper<ResponseList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListWrapper<ResponseList>> call, Response<ListWrapper<ResponseList>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("Callback", " Message: " + response.body().items);
                List<ResponseList> re = new ArrayList<>();
                re.addAll(response.body().items);
                ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(re);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener((ClickListener<abcList>) (view, data, position) -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Position = "+position+"\n Item = "+data.getNo(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          
                    String no = data.getNo();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("no", no);

                    DetailViewFragment detailedFragment = new DetailViewFragment();
                    detailedFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                    if (mTwoPane) {
                        layoutId = abcBind.detail.getId();
                    }
                    else {
                        layoutId = abcBind.fragment.getId();
                    }


                    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) view.getContext();
                    activity
                            .getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(layoutId, detailedFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                });

            } else {
                Log.d("Callback", "Code: " + response.code() + " Message: " + response.message());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ListWrapper<ResponseList>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to make your `ABCFragment` `abstract` with one `abstract` function  `int getCategoryId()`, in addition to rest of the code. All other 3 `Fragments` ,  extending `ABCFragment'` , will have to only  implement this function and return desired `categoryId`.

By changing this line as :

```
restAPI.getAPI(langId, getCategoryId()).enqueue(abcCallback);
```

you obtain `categoryId`  through method.

All the fragments extending  `ABCFragment`, will have it's layout and all other methods already defined and available.